# Windows Phone 8.1 App Bar Minimized

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am developing windows phone 8.1 app. In windows phone 8 app bar has property known as mode which when set to minimized collapses the app bar. What is the equivalent property or way in win phone 8.1 to collapse the app bar

Answer (score 0):

[AppBar.hide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229668.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is what you're looking for. It's as straightforward as it sounds! :-)